# Alter Drupal datalayer client-side

Tags: 7, google-analytics

We are using the datalayer drupal module, and am trying to add new data to the data layer dynamically on client side. I can access the dataLayer object within site, and I push custom data to it, but everytime I push something new it creates a new datalayer object. Can I add to an existing object?

[image]

I only need the first dataLayer object and want to add more data to it, is that possible at client side with Javascript?

If not, I can just have it as it is, but then am not sure how to access granular information within GTM, for example how do I access the values under `entityTaxonomy.sections` from GTM?

I am using [datalayer](https://www.drupal.org/project/datalayer) module.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!